# Chrome/Firefox plug-in for automatically opening the dev tools and executing code in the console

Tags: plugins, devtools

Is it possible to write a Chrome/Firefox plug-in that can automatically open the dev tools for every open tab and execute code in the console?
I have already done this with Selenium, but I would like to have it as a plug-in.

Unfortunately, I haven't found a chrome api yet that allows you to automatically insert and execute code in devtools.

I would be very grateful to anyone who could help me get a step closer.

PS:Since I don't add the plugin to the store, developer API's or other unconventional alternatives can also be used.